# If Else Statement Quick Error

Tags: html, if-statement, model-view-controller

I'd like to make the div id=Delete visible ONLY when the mode="Edit" // Can't figure it out, thanks for any help. Code is below. Seems super simple, but I can't get it to cooperate.

```
@model Credentials.Models.OEMAdd

@{
    string mode;
    if (Model.provider.Id == null)
    {
        mode = "Add";
    }
    else
    {
        mode = "Edit";
    }

    ViewBag.Title = mode + " OEM Provider";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        <div id="Verify" style="display:none"><input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" value="Verify Login & Save" /></div>
        <div id="Delete" style="float:right; margin-right:995px; margin-top:18px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Profile</a></div>
        <br /> <a href="@Url.Action("OEMProviders", new { id = Model.provider.Company.Id } )" class="btn btn-lg">Cancel</a>
        <br />
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity? Which languages/frameworks is this with the `@` syntax? is it WinJS or something?

Comment: it is asp.net mvc. That is the razor syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use an if around the this div

```
 @if(mode == "edit"){
    <div id="Delete" style="float:right; margin-right:995px; margin-top:18px"><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">Delete Profile</a></div>  
        }
```